# How do I get numeric values in an array in str_replace()’s search parameter to map the way I expect?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

```
php > echo str_replace(
    array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
    array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'),
    '01234567890abcdef') . PHP_EOL;
klmnopghijkklmnop
```

I expected this `str_replace()` call to give me something like `abcdefghijklmnop`. But it seems that the numeric strings in my search array are being treated as something other than strings.

I am ultimately just going for the functionality of [`tr(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) (e.g., `tr a-f k-p | tr 0-9 a-j`) but with pure php instead of a shellout, of course.

I see this same behavior on php-5.4.10--pl0-gentoo and php-5.5.4-pl0-gentoo, so I assume it’s not just a fluke with one version of PHP. Why does str_replace() treat numerics in the search array oddly—and *how* is it treating them anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

It just replace already replaced values that is why you get "strange results"

Example:

First result letter is `K` instead of `A` it's because `0` was replaced to `A` then `A` was replaced to `K`. When you think this way you will see proper result of this functin.

Comment: Wow. I thought about this very issue when writing my `tr` snippet, makes sense! I can get the right answer by just reversing my arrays (or by following others’ suggestions to use `strstr()` instead).

Answer (score 2):

You can use use [strtr](https://www.php.net/strtr) function in PHP:

```
echo strtr( '01234567890abcdef', '0123456789abcdef', 'abcdefghijklmnop' ) . PHP_EOL;
// abcdefghijaklmnop
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacements are applied in order and the entire string is scanned from beginning to end on for each replacement option.

It is normal for `0` to be replaced with `a` in the first replacement run and then for `a` to be replaced with `k` in the 10th replacement run.

What you are trying to achieve is to not perform replacements on already replace strings. I think  that would be considered unintuitive / unexpected behavior.

Tell us what real use cases you would like this to apply to so we can help with more pragmatical and direct solutions; the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is strtr - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php